# Function clarification

Tags: functions

I know the fact that if a function $f$ is inverse of another function $g$, then domain and codomain of $f$ are codomain and domain of $g$ respectively.
My book has written that exponential function $a^x$ has codomain of $R$, but since logarithmic function is its inverse then why logarithmic function's domain doesn't matches with codomain of $a^x$?

Comment: It's the *range* of a function that matters.  You can set the codomain of a function at your convenience.  In the case of publishing a book, it's easier to typeset $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ then $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^*_+$, so I guess that's the reason the author set the codomain of $f$ to $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter if codomain does matters because codomain is responsible for the function's classification as into and onto. If I choose codomain by myself then it may turn a into function to onto or vice versa

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 : Note that our usage differs (see my answer). You use "codomain" and "range" where I use "range" and "image". Usage varies widely. But still, +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

For a function $f:X\to Y$, your book is probably distinguishing between *codomain* $Y$ and the *image* $f(X)$.

It is always true that $f(X)\subseteq Y$, but it isn't true that $f(X)=Y$ unless $f$ is surjective ("onto").

The meaning and use of the terms "codomain", "range", and "image" varies, so you should be sure to check the exact definition of the words according to your text.

More exactly, the domain of $f^{-1}$ is the image $f(X)$, and the image of $f^{-1}$ is $X$ (you might be using "codomain" rather than "image" or "range").

(In all of the texts I have used, $Y$ is the "range" and $f(X)$ is the "image", so that the image always lies within the range; I've never used the term "codomain", though I understand it is more commonplace today.)

Comment: I know that a function is subjective when its range and codomain set are same, but does this mean that for defining purposes we can took codomain of exponential function as R and when want to make it subjective (to make its inverse defined) turn its codomain set as R+.   If similar thing is done with other function we can convert a non subjective function into surjective

Comment: there should be strict set of codomain defined along with a particular function